# How can a VB macro know its location?

Tags: vba, ms-office

How can use relative locations in VB in a word/excel macro in office 2010?

I'm running an executable file through the shell function in the macro and I want it to use its own location to call the .exe, which will be in the lame location as the macro'd doc.

Hope that's clear enough to try to answer?

Thank you!

Comment: in the VBA Project window, do you see anything other than 1 project and one `ThisDocument` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Thisworkbook.Path`. For example:

```
Shell """" & Thisworkbook.Path & "\myprog.exe"""
```

Notice the additional double-quotes to enclose the `path\name`, this is a safety measure in case the folders' names contain some space characters.

Comment: Thanks but I got '424' object required in word, tried "ThisDocument" and got file not found error, in the debugger 'ThisDocument' resolves to an appdata location, not the location the document is saved in. Any ideas? I'm yet to try on excel.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @A.S.H for putting me on the right path.

The answer was to use ActiveDocument.Path

Thanks again

Comment: ActiveDocument is the currently active document, so it might not be where the macro is if there is another document open in the same Application